# Show compactness of a set given by inequalities

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Show that the subset $A=\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\Bbb R^n |−1≤x_1 ≤x_2 ≤···≤x_n ≤1\}$ is compact.

A is contain in an open cover as it is contained in $\Bbb R^n$.
Therefore there exists a finite sub cover which is the union of the open balls centred at $x_i$ for $i \in I$ with radius $>2$ implying compactedness. Am I on the right track or where have i gone wrong?

Comment: Struggling with The font of R as you can see

Comment: Perhaps, finding a relevant continuous function, or doing this as an intersection of several compact sets? For example, $A = \bigcap_i A_i$ where $A_i = \{-1 \leq x_i \leq x_{i+1}\leq 1\}$

Comment: You don't get to choose the open cover, you have to find a finite subcover for *any* open cover. The open cover you have to work with might not include the open balls you describe (it might only contain balls of radius $1/2$, e.g.).

Comment: But I agree with Ilya here, go another route. The finite subcover condition is a more difficult thing to prove. You might just try showing it's closed; it's clearly bounded, and then you're done.

Comment: ah yes okay i understand. thanks for the help

Comment: @Ilya: the sets $A_i$ are not compact when $n\ge 3$.

Comment: @user59363: that's why I did not give an answer, rather a comment to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed using Heine-Borel theorem. The set you presented is clearly bounded, and it is closed, therefore, it is compact.

To check that it is closed, simply consider any point $y\notin A$. Then, see that for a sufficient small neighborhood of $y$, $V_y$, then $V_y \subset \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$. This will follow simply assuming that one of the inequalities defining $A$ does not hold, and seeing that it will not hold for points near $y$.